# MVC3 Webgrid Paging and Sorting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I'm using MVC3 webgrid to display, sort and paginate data.  The display is fine, but when I click on a new page or request a sort, it opens the table in a brand new window on it's own?  Anybody know why this happens?  It is contained within a partial view.

The code for the grid is as follows:

```
@{

var grid = new WebGrid(
    source: Model, 
    defaultSort: "StudyName", 
    rowsPerPage: 10, 
    canPage: true, 
    canSort: true);
}

<div>

@if (Model.Any())
{
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "resultTable",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
columns: grid.Columns(
//List of columns
)

)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my own question as I have found the solution, and by sharing it may help somebody else.

Effectively, I simply had to include the following line in the webgrid declaration:

```
    ajaxUpdateContainerId: "tableDiv"
```

Where "tableDiv" is the containing element.